# Spring 23 Platform Event tests broken

Tags: apex, unit-test, platform-event, spring23

As of Spring 23, we have several failing tests which involved publishing Platform Events, collecting them in a static variable, publishing them, then in the test, retrieving the static variable to assert size and contents.

It appears that this change ([Apex Static Variables Are Reset Within a Transaction Between Groups of Platform Event–Triggered Flow Interviews](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_runtime_apex_static_variables.htm&type=5&release=242)) has a side effect that's clearing the static collections we were using in the tests, thus breaking them.

Without the ability to reference the published events in the static variable, I cannot come up with a good way to test that the events were published or what's in them. It seems my options are:

1. Remove the assertions and only worry about coverage
2. Create a listener for each event being published so as to be able to retrieve them after Test.stopTest().

Neither of these options are all that appealing. Am I overlooking another means to test?

Comment: Where is your static variable that is accumulating the events to be published located?

Comment: @DanielBallinger It's in the class that publishes the event

Comment: You should engineer this to allow mocking of the publication itself (e.g. encapsulate just the `EventBus.publish` in a mockable way - either a separate class you mock or as a virtual method you override in your test) for checking it gets published, and a separate unit test of the processing you initiate from the platform event subscriber - use best practice and put all of this in a trigger handler, not in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

One way to unit test whether a Platform Event is published with expected contents (without using listeners) is to use the [Unit of Work pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl).   An implementation of this is contained in the GitHub repo [apex-common aka fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common).

Your code looks like the following

```
fflib_ISobjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitofWork.newInstance();

...  construct the PlatformEvent here

uow.registerPublishAfterSuccessTransaction(myPlatformEvent);

...

uow.commitWork(); // this calls EventBus.publish()
```

and your testmethod mocks a `UnitOfWork` (in my example, using [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks) although you could also use [Amoss](https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss))  and then verifies that the `registerPublishAfterSuccessTransaction` was called with the expected argument

```
fflib_apexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

// Given mock UnitOfWork
fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);
// Given mock UoW injected
Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow); 

// when code under test invoked
new MyClass().doStuff();

// then verify event constructed, constructed as expected, and published
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.times(1)
                        .description('myEvent sb published')))
  .registerPublishAfterSuccessTransaction(
      fflib_Match.sObjectOfType(MyEvent__e__e.SObjectType)
  );

((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.times(1)
                        .description('myEvent sb published')))
  .registerPublishAfterSuccessTransaction(
      fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
         MyEvent__e.Field1__c => myExpectedField1Val,
         MyEvent__e.Field2__c => myExpectedField2Val
          })
  );

((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.times(1)
                        .description('commitwork sb called')))
  .commitWork();
```

**Notes:**

1. Since the above is based on the `fflib` architecture, you need an `Application.cls`. This will include an entry for `MyEvent__e` in the `UnitOfWork` factory as follows:

   ```
   public static final fflib_Application.UnitOfWorkFactory UnitOfWork =
    new fflib_Application.UnitOfWorkFactory(
            new List<SObjectType> { // list in dependency order (e.g. Accounts before Contacts)
               ...
               MyEvent__e.SObjectType
            }
    );
   ```
2. The approach above of course works for normal DML (`registerNew(myObject)`, `registerDirty(myObject)`, etc and even sending email (`uow.registerEmail(email)`) so you can see if your DML and/or outbound apex email was constructed properly in a unit test.

Comment: Thanks, so if I didn't have time to refactor our code to make use of fflib right now, I could mock the publisher class and do essentially the same thing, correct?

Comment: yes, and the degree to which you want to mock can vary -- use a dependency-injected object to going all the way to the Test.StubAPI (which is what apexmocks and amoss are built on).  The mocking frameworks are super powerful